# what is the use of "$" in out.format of toString() and how toString() works?

Tags: java, tostring

```
public String toString() 
{
 StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
 Formatter out = new Formatter(result);
 out.format("$%.2f%n%d dollars%n%d quarters%n" +"%d dimes%n%d pennies%n",
 total, dollars, quarters, dimes, pennies);
 return result.toString();
}
```

In this Snippet of code, Why StringBuffer, Formatter are used?
And how toString() is called in a class automatically without making it to call in main() ?

Comment: There are some methods, like `System.out.print` or `System.out.println` that will automatically call the `toString` method of the object passed as argument.

Comment: And, `"$"` is not an special character in formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the code can be written more concisely as

```
return String.format("$%.2f%n%d dollars%n%d quarters%n%d dimes%n%d pennies%n",
    total, dollars, quarters, dimes, pennies);
```

> what is the use of “$”

It has no special meaning here (as a format specifier). It just prints a literal dollar sign. So you'd get an output like "$2.00".

> And how toString() is called in a class automatically without making it to call in main()

Most methods to produce text output (like `System.out.println)` take any kind of Object as a parameter and call `toString` on it by themselves. This is a convenience that also takes care of `null` (by printing "null" instead of crashing with a NullPointerException).